# Q. Is there a way to create Foursquare user account via Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

I am building a mobile app which requires creating Foursquare user account from registration page of the app itself. Does Foursquare API have this option.

You response is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, no. And it's **very unlikely** it will be added someday.

Read the documentation: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/